# Error al extraer una array en angular FormBuilder

Tags: array, angular, json

***Estaba intentando hacen un service el cual del lado de mi backend con endpoint pueda retornar un usuario con una lista de mascota pero me salia error, decidi crear mi json manualmente y creando una clase Usuario.ts. Excelente me retorna mi usuario pero al momento de recorrer mi mascota tengo un error en mi Html pero veo que si esta inicializado. tengo dudas aun estoy aprendiendo pero ya llevo unas cuantas horas y no encuentro solución. Una mano de como extraer los datos  con mi array y pueda reflejar.

*ngFor="let mascota of usuarioForm.get('mascotas').controls; por que al poner controls me sale que el object is possibly null ? Pero si estoy ingresando directamente. Su ayuda

```js
import {
  Component,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  FormArray,
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';
import {
  UrlSegment
} from '@angular/router';
import {
  ObservedValueUnionFromArray
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  Mascota
} from 'src/app/clases/Mascota';
import {
  Usuario
} from 'src/app/clases/Usuario';
import {
  SearchNombreService
} from 'src/app/servicios/searchNombre/search-nombre.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-buscar-nombre',
  templateUrl: './buscar-nombre.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./buscar-nombre.component.css']
})
export class BuscarNombreComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }
  formularioPrincipal: FormGroup;

  constructor(private searchService: SearchNombreService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

    const usuarioBackend = {

      "nombres": "Steeven David",
      "apellidos": "Rodriguez Zhunio",
      "direccion": "Bastion Popular",
      "celular": "09XXXXXXXX",
      "email": "srodriguez@email.com",
      "age": "27",
      "mascotas": [{

        "nombre": "Kyra",
        "raza": "Golden",
        "color": "Amarillo",
        "nacimiento": "2023-12-31"
      }]

    }


    this.formularioPrincipal = this.formBuilder.group({
      searchInput: [''],
      nombres: [usuarioBackend.nombres, Validators.required],
      apellidos: [usuarioBackend.apellidos, Validators.required],
      celular: [usuarioBackend.celular, Validators.required],
      direccion: [usuarioBackend.direccion, Validators.required],
      age: [usuarioBackend.age, Validators.required],
      email: [usuarioBackend.email, [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      mascotas: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })

    const arrayMascotas = this.formularioPrincipal.get('mascotas') as FormArray;
    usuarioBackend.mascotas.forEach(mascotas => {
      arrayMascotas.push(this.agregarMascotas(mascotas));
    })
  }



  agregarMascotas(mascotas: any): FormGroup {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      nombre: [mascotas.nombre],
      raza: [mascotas.raza],
      nacimiento: [mascotas.nacimiento],
      color: [mascotas.color]
    });
  };

  get mascotas() {
    return this.formularioPrincipal.get('mascotas') as FormArray;
  };






  /*Obteniendo la mascota

  agregarMascota(mascota:Mascota){
  this.mascotas.push(this.formBuilder.group({
    nombre:[mascota.nombre, Validators.required],
    raza:[mascota.raza,Validators.required],
    nacimiento:[mascota.nacimiento,Validators.required],
    color:[mascota.color,Validators.required]
  }))
  }*/




  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Topbar Search -->

<form [formGroup]="formularioPrincipal" (ngSubmit)="search()">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-auto my-1 " style="max-width:500px ;">
      <br>
      <div class="input-group container" style="max-width: 300px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control bg-light border-0 small" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" formControlName="searchInput" name="searchInput">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                        <i class="fas fa-search fa-sm"></i>
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
      <div class="row">

        <div class="p-5">

          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
              <input for="nombres" formControlName="nombres" name="nombres" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="nombres" placeholder="Nombres" readonly>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input for="apellidos" formControlName="apellidos" name="apellidos" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
              <input for="celular" formControlName="celular" name="celular" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="celular" placeholder="Celular">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
              <input for="age" formControlName="age" name="age" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="age" placeholder="Age">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input for="direccion" formControlName="direccion" name="direccion" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="direccion" placeholder="Direccion del domicilio">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input for="email" formControlName="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control form-control-user" id="email" placeholder="Email Address">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Mascota Formulario-->
    <div formArrayName="mascotas">
      <div *ngIf="formularioPrincipal.get('mascotas')">
        <div *ngFor="let mascota of formularioPrincipal.get('mascotas').controls; ">
          <div class="card border-0 shadow-lg mx-auto my-1 " style="max-width:500px ;">
            <div>

              <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
              <div class="row">

                <div class="p-5">

                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                      <input for="nombre" formControlName="nombre" name="nombre" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="nombre" placeholder="Mascota">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input for="raza" formControlName="raza" name="raza" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="raza" placeholder="Raza">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                      <input for="color" formControlName="color" name="color" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="color" placeholder="Color">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                      <input for="nacimiento" formControlName="nacimiento" name="nacimiento" type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="nacimiento" placeholder="Fecha Nacimiento">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```